# Limit to number of terms in an expression?

Tags: compiler-errors, swift

Edit: This is confirmed by apple as a compiler error.

The first `if` expression below (17 terms) compiles, and produces the expected result (`false`).
The second `if` expression (18 terms) fails with the error message:

> Cannot invoke '||' with an argument list of type '($T106,$T110)'.

The two expressions are identical except for the extra term.

I have no problem working around the problem, but I just don't understand what it is complaining about.  Can someone enlighten me as to what stupid mistake I am making?  Be gentle, very inexperienced coder here.

```
import Darwin

var a = -1
if
    a == 0 ||
        a == 1 ||
        a == 2 ||
        a == 3 ||
        a == 4 ||
        a == 5 ||
        a == 6 ||
        a == 7 ||
        a == 8 ||
        a == 9 ||
        a == 10 ||
        a == 11 ||
        a == 12 ||
        a == 13 ||
        a == 14 ||
        a == 15 ||
        a == 16 ||
        a == 17 { println("value was true") } else { println("value was false")}

if
    a == 0 ||
        a == 1 ||
        a == 2 ||
        a == 3 ||
        a == 4 ||
        a == 5 ||
        a == 6 ||
        a == 7 ||
        a == 8 ||
        a == 9 ||
        a == 10 ||
        a == 11 ||
        a == 12 ||
        a == 13 ||
        a == 14 ||
        a == 15 ||
        a == 16 ||
        a == 17 ||
        a == 18 { println("value was true") } else { println("value was false")}
```

Comment: I cannot see an obvious error in your code, and I can reproduce the problem already with 12 terms. You should file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: It has become apparent, that swift still has problems with anything that has a lot of operands/arguments. For example a long list of arguments in a function would crash SourceKitService.

Comment: Interestingly, in an iOS Playground in Xcode6-Beta6, it starts complaining after 11 terms.

Comment: Apple bug report 18078691

Comment: Apple confirmed bug, closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yay for bug reporting. In the meantime, anything that leads to a logical OR with 17 clauses probably isn't the most concise way to express whatever you're trying to do anyway. Have you looked into a `switch` statement or direct use of the `ClosedInterval` type?

Comment: Interesting to note that as of beta 6, while this doesn't compile, swiftc does offer a better warning: `expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Comment: Yes the 18 clauses is a bit much.  In my original code I had many fewer clauses, but they were more complex, and I got the same error.  I wrote the above attempting to build the simplest case possible and reproduce the problem.  With such a simple clause, it took 18 terms to fail.  I can't even find the section of code that caused this in the first place, I think I must have rewritten that code several times by now.

Comment: Henry, could you please post an answer stating that this has been confirmed as a bug by Apple so that the question can be completed?

Answer (score 3):

While the bug is solved you can use this:

```
switch a {
case 0...17:
    println("value was true")
default:
    println("value was false")
}
```